# ios/objective-c: Interaction of Button Action with Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, dismiss

For a login screen using Storyboard I have a button for Login.  However, when the user touches the button, frequently, what happens is the keyboard is dismissed, the view moves down and then the user has to tap a second time to trigger the button's action method.

I think the issue may have something to do with the method being used to dismiss the keyboard, `self.view endEditing:YES`.  Or maybe the event attached to the action method for the button, `Touch Up Inside`.  Or maybe the code that makes the view move based on what field you are in (shown below).

Can anyone suggest the right way to do this...IE when the user touches the button, the action method is called the first time.

I still would like the keyboard dismissed if the user clicks somewhere OTHER than the button or inside another textfield.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
//method dismissing keyboard
- (void) tapped
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

The event for the button's action method is `"Touch Up Inside"`

In addition, I am using the following code to make the view move up and down as needed based on the textfield you are in:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    if ([sender isEqual:_username]) {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -70., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
           }
    else if([sender isEqual:_password]) {
         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -90., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if([sender isEqual:_Email]) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -110., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    if ([sender isEqual:_username]) {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y +70., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if ([sender isEqual:_password]) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y +90., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if ([sender isEqual:_Email]) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y +110., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your touches in touchesBegan method and then can determine that whether it is touched on button or not... like that

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(button pointInside:location withEvent:nil)
    {
        // touched on Button

        // call your button method here
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line is giving errors expected ')' and expected '>' Is there a typo?